# Radon Transform over a finite domain

Tags: fourier-transform, transformation, line-integrals, radon-transform

Im having trouble understanding how to apply the Radon Transform.

Algorithmically, it is simply applying the line integral of the form:

$$\mathbb{R}[f(x,y)] = \int_L f(x(s), y(s))ds$$

where $x(s) = r\text{cos}(\theta) + s \text{sin}(\theta)$, and $y(s) = r\text{sin}(\theta) - s \text{cos}(\theta)$

I can evaluate this simply for the 2D Gaussian $f(x,y) = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$, however, for the following problem, I cannot figure out how to set the domain for the integral.

**Problem:**

Given the function $f(x,y) = 1$, over the domain $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. Find the Radon Transform $\mathbb{R}[f(x,y)] = R(r, \theta)$